# Why javacc-maven-plugin will not generate Node and SimpleNode for second jjt package

Tags: java, maven, parsing, javacc

```
> mvn javacc:jjtree-javacc


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building try 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- javacc-maven-plugin:2.6:jjtree-javacc (default-cli) @ try ---
[WARNING] File encoding for grammars has not been configured, using platform default encoding, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Java Compiler Compiler Version 6.1_2 (Tree Builder)
(type "jjtree" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file /SOME_WHEREtry/src/main/jjtree/play/parser/expr/ExpressionParser.jjt . . .
opt:java
File "Node.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "SimpleNode.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ExpressionParserTreeConstants.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ExpressionParserVisitor.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ExpressionParserDefaultVisitor.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "JJTExpressionParserState.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
Annotated grammar generated successfully in /SOME_WHEREtry/target/javacc-1449905090759/node/ExpressionParser.jj
Java Compiler Compiler Version 6.1_2 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file /SOME_WHEREtry/target/javacc-1449905090759/node/ExpressionParser.jj . . .
File "TokenMgrError.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ParseException.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "Token.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "SimpleCharStream.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
Parser generated successfully.
Java Compiler Compiler Version 6.1_2 (Tree Builder)
(type "jjtree" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file /SOME_WHEREtry/src/main/jjtree/play/parser/expr2/Expr2Parser.jjt . . .
opt:java
File "Expr2ParserTreeConstants.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "Expr2ParserVisitor.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "Expr2ParserDefaultVisitor.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "JJTExpr2ParserState.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
Annotated grammar generated successfully in /SOME_WHEREtry/target/javacc-1449905090970/node/Expr2Parser.jj
Java Compiler Compiler Version 6.1_2 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file /SOME_WHEREtry/target/javacc-1449905090970/node/Expr2Parser.jj . . .
File "TokenMgrError.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ParseException.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "Token.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "JavaCharStream.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
Parser generated successfully.
[INFO] Processed 2 grammars
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Only generate Node and SimpleNode for `play/parser/expr/ExpressionParser.jjt` not for `play/parser/expr2/Expr2Parser.jjt`

Even I set `NODE_PACKAGE="play.parser.expr2";` still not work.

How can I generate `Node` and `SimpleNode` for second jjt package ?